# nginx: [emerg] unknown "request_url" variable

Tags: nginx, wordpress, google-compute-engine

I am running a Wordpress site on Google Compute Engine. It's Nginx and used to work correctly. After a server restart it no longer starts up Nginx. I receive :

`nginx: [emerg] unknown "request_url" variable
/opt/bitnami/nginx/scripts/ctl.sh: 77: [: Illegal number: 
/opt/bitnami/nginx/scripts/ctl.sh : Nginx could not be started`

I have no idea even where to begin to look for the cause of the error. Any hints, tips, or flat out answers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The correct variable name is `$request_uri`

Comment: In my nginx-app.conf file it is written $request_uri. So I don't know where it si getting this error from actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @Alexey Ten said, correct variable is `$request_uri` 
Also you can check that this variable is not defined too late on nginx config file.

UPDATE:

Problem solved with restoring an existing image of GCE instance.

Comment: It's actually written $request_uri in my nginx-app.conf file. and it's the second line so I don't believe it's called too late.

Comment: Did you checked if the service is started? `systemctl status nginx` If it's possible provide the output.

Comment: It is not started (Unit nginx.service could not be found.)  When I attempt to start the service is when I get the original error.

Comment: Can you execute the following command in order to find if there is any reference to "request_url" in the code?
`grep -rnw /opt/bitnami/nginx/ -e 'request_url'`

Comment: Thanks Albert, but I gave up on the "correct" way and went the video game way. I remembered to save (often) so I removed the VM and loaded up a new one and restored onto it. So I don't know what caused it, or if it will happen again, but I am up and running for now.

Comment: I've updated my answer @NetApex.